# bat files: "command not found"

Tags: batch-file

I have two bat files
a) is H:\AD009\APK_apps_OppoGallery2\OppoGallery2\OppoGallery3D_N1\123.bat

```
   ant release
```

b) is D:\Users\Administrator\Desktop

```
@echo off 
rem 关闭自动输出
rem 接收输入
:begin
set home=H:\N1_ROM_svn685\apq\linux
set target=msm8960
set psfile=c:/ps.log


set input=0
echo PROJECT=%home%
echo 0: adbshell
echo 1: vendor_server
echo 2: libcameraservice
echo 3: pushapk
echo 4: compileapk
echo -1: exit
set /p input=请输入字符串: 

rem 输出得到的输入信息

echo 您输入的字符串是：%input%

adb remount
if %input%==0 goto adbshell
if %input%==1 goto vendor_server
if %input%==2 goto libcameraservice
if %input%==3 goto pushapk
if %input%==4 goto compileapk
if %input%==-1 goto exit


:libmmcamera_frameproc.so
echo libandroid_runtime.so
adb push %home%\out\target\product\%target%\system\lib\libmmcamera_frameproc.so /system/lib/
goto kill

:vendor_server
echo camera.msm8960.so
adb push %home%\out\target\product\%target%\system\lib\hw\camera.msm8960.so /system/lib/hw/
adb push %home%\out\target\product\%target%\system\lib\liboemcamera.so                         /system/lib
adb push %home%\out\target\product\%target%\system\lib\libmmcamera_3a_legacy.so                /system/lib
adb push %home%\out\target\product\%target%\system\lib\libmmcamera_statsproc31.so              /system/lib
adb push %home%\out\target\product\%target%\system\lib\libmmcamera_plugin.so                   /system/lib
adb push %home%\out\target\product\%target%\system\lib\libmmcamera_frameproc.so                /system/lib
adb push %home%\out\target\product\%target%\system\lib\libmmcamera_cpp.so                      /system/lib
adb push %home%\out\target\product\%target%\system\lib\libmmcamera_interface.so                /system/lib
adb push %home%\out\target\product\%target%\system\lib\libmmcamera_interface2.so               /system/lib
adb push %home%\out\target\product\%target%\system\lib\libchromatix_imx135_default_video.so    /system/lib
adb push %home%\out\target\product\%target%\system\lib\libchromatix_imx135_preview.so          /system/lib
adb push %home%\out\target\product\%target%\system\lib\libchromatix_imx135_zsl.so              /system/lib
adb push %home%\out\target\product\%target%\system\lib\libchromatix_imx135_hfr_120fps.so       /system/lib
adb push %home%\out\target\product\%target%\system\lib\libchromatix_s5k6a3yx_default_video.so  /system/lib
adb push %home%\out\target\product\%target%\system\lib\libchromatix_s5k6a3yx_preview.so        /system/lib
adb push %home%\out\target\product\%target%\system\lib\libchromatix_s5k6a3yx_zsl.so            /system/lib
adb push %home%\out\target\product\%target%\system\lib\libchromatix_s5k6a3yx_video_hd.so       /system/lib
adb push %home%\out\target\product\%target%\system\lib\hw\camera.msm8960.so                    /system/lib/hw
goto kill

:libcameraservice
echo libcameraservice.so
adb push %home%\out\target\product\%target%\system\lib\libcameraservice.so /system/lib/
goto kill

:pushapk
echo oppogallery.apk
goto kill

:compileapk
cd /d H:\AD009\APK_apps_OppoGallery2\OppoGallery2\OppoGallery3D_N1
start H:\AD009\APK_apps_OppoGallery2\OppoGallery2\OppoGallery3D_N1\123.bat
goto kill

:kill
adb shell ps > %psfile%
python D:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\hello.py %psfile%
adb shell kill %errorlevel%
goto begin

:adbshell
adb shell

:end
set input = 0;
goto begin

:exit
echo good bye
pause
```

I enter 4, I want the label "compileapk" to be executed, but it report can't find ant

when i typed "echo %path%", I can find the ant'spath is in the output.

But when I double click the 123.bat manually, it can be executed.

Comment: Don't use start, execute the bat file directly, start does a CreateProcess for cmd.exe which creates a fresh command interpreter

Comment: @rene: when you call a batch file "directly" from inside another batch file the first batch file will be terminated when the called one terminates. You need to use `call` instead.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name then is there some mean to replace "start" command, call didn't effect.

Comment: @rene, every time i need to enter the directory and double-click,it's boring me. I want to collect them all in one entrance

Comment: @harris: `call` *will* work. The error message "command not found" simply means that `ant.bat` is not in your search path (`PATH` variable). You need to either fully qualify where `ant.bat` is located (e.g. `call "%ANT_HOME%\bin\ant.bat"`) or include it in the system `PATH`.